# React Styled Component, defined Inside Component and Outside Return?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

We have a Styled Component. My styled component is defined within a Function component, but outside its return method. See code below.

Someone mentioned a styled component should be defined outside a component in general. Is this true? Where is the best location to put StyledTableCell?

```
const ProcedureServicesRowHeader = () => {

  const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)`
    && {
      padding: 1.5px;
      color: green;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <TableRow>
      <StyledTableCell textAlign="left">Service</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell textAlign="center">Units</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell textAlign="right">Charge</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell textAlign="right">Total</StyledTableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};

export default ProcedureServicesRowHeader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a new component reference on ever render, which causes the full subtree to remount. Define it so that it is statically available, outside of the render, or in this case outside `ProcedureServicesRowHeader`.